# LocalConnection var into URLRequest

Tags: actionscript-3

i use LocalConnection between two swf in the same page.
What i'm trying to do is to use a String sent from one swf to the other, as  variable into my URLRequest...

So i can trace "myVar" into the function chemin, but i didn't find how to use it into URLRequest

thank's for your help

swf that receive the var :

```
var lc:LocalConnection=new LocalConnection();
lc.client=this;
lc.connect("callBig");

function chemin(myVar:String){
trace(myVar)
}

var chargementXML:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var fichier:URLRequest = new URLRequest(myVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lc:LocalConnection=new LocalConnection();
lc.client=this;
lc.connect("callBig");
var receivedVar:String = "";

// somewhere else
function chemin(myVar:String){
    receivedVar = myVar;
}

// later
var chargementXML:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
vars.myVar = receivedVar;
chargementXML.data = vars;
var fichier:URLRequest = new URLRequest(myVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some references to help you out.

- **URLRequest.data**: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#data
- **URLVariables**: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html

So, if you want to pass some variables in your request, you do the following:

1. Create `new URLVariables()` object
2. Assign it's reference to `URLRequest.data` field.

---

```
var fichier:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
urlVars["myVarName"] = myVar;
fichier.data = urlVars;
```

This way your server side app will recieve a variable myVarName with value of myVar.